# How to request user location from HLR

Tags: windows, networking, telecommunication, ss7

I'm a software developer with very little knowledge on telco,  recently my boss asked me to find a way to request user location with their imsi from the HLR. I have never done such thing before, i work mostly on high end applications. I've done some research, read some articles, like on dialogic.com, but until now i haven't found clear instructions on have to make it.

So can someone explain me what are all the steps i should take in order to make it? I'm working on windows but a linux based solution will be good to. Please consider I'm a newbie.

Comment: Hello,
Finally after many days.I think i found what i was looking for here http://documentation.telestax.com/core/gmlc/GMLC_Admin_Guide.html

Comment: I know it's an old post, but this paper may be useful:
https://ccdcoe.org/uploads/2018/10/Art-17-We-Know-Where-You-Are.pdf

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do it, of course, but all depends on the core network. If it is up to 3g, you could (depending on the operator) either do ATI against HLR based on IMSI, or send an SRI-SM query to the HLR and in response get the VLR id.
then send PSI (Provide subscriber info) query with Location Information tag  to the VLR which you got from HLR.
In response of PSI the VLR/MSC will respond back with LAC and Cellid of

subscriber. For newer (4-5G) mobile networks, there is an explanation here http://4g5gworld.com/blog/lcs-architecture-lte-eps

Answer (score 0):

The interface to the HLR is usually not an open interface - it is an SS7 based interface on what is a closed network for operators.

The information in the HLR and VLR (Visitor Location Register - a local copy of the HLR on visited switches) and the VLR is not usually available externally. Some of the information would never be shared, but there are some services which will allow you query some HLR info - for example (I have not used these and cannot vouch for them):

- https://www.hlr-lookups.com
- http://www.vianett.com/en/products/overview/hlr-number-lookup

If you wanted to implement a service like this yourself, you would need a gateway between the IP and SS7 networks.

Answer (score 0):

The HLR lookup service provides information for IMSI and roaming MSC. A MSC have country code and network code. If this is the only information which serves the purpose the , you can get lookup services from any service provider , just by checking the coverage. If you are telecom company and have SS7/Sigtran level access to the mobile operators then can develop your own lookup gateway.

https://www.cspsprotocol.com/what-is-hlr-lookup/

Answer (score 0):

I found what i needed with Telestax Restcomm GMLC server. It's available here
https://github.com/RestComm/gmlc
But be aware that the solution only works on Linux server, because windows does not implement the SCTP Stack.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post, but if it's any help to others, I use a company called Data Soap for HLR lookups and they provide information about phone network, along with the originating country.

- https://www.datasoap.co.uk/data-quality-services/hlr-lookup